# neck-deep wallow

Tags: meaning

*The overriding problem with True Detective 2 is its neck-deep wallow in debasement and self-pity.*

Source: http://unclebarky.com/reviews_files/1f4f0c6e5f560559193d0dca93b604d9-1965.html

Could you please rewrite the phrase "neck-deep wallow in debasement". I am not able to understand what it exactly means.

Comment: *The overriding problem with True Detective 2 is it's **wallowing up to its neck** in debasement and self-pity*. The optional qualifier *up to its neck* is just another figurative usage easily connected to an action like *wallowing*, where it simply means *very deeply* (also fitting in nicely with *debasement* - figuratively extrapolating low morals from "spatial" lowness at the *base/bottom* of things).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> its neck-deep wallow in debasement and self-pity.

Wallow is a noun that means '[an act of wallowing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/wallow)'. To 'wallow in' is a verb that literally means

> (Of a person) indulge in an unrestrained way in (something that one finds pleasurable).

One of the examples is "he had been wallowing in self-pity". So we often use "wallow" together with "self-pity."  It is like someone is standing in self-pity. In this case the writer says that the show is wallowing in self pity.

Neck-deep" means up-to-one's-neck, so it is about as deep as one can wallow in water and still be able to breathe.

The article also mentions "debasement," which is generally perceived as another negative characteristic: when something is [debase](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/debase)d, it is reduced in value. THis can include moral value.

So the show enjoys standing or wallowing up to its neck (about as far as possible) in both self-pity and debasement. The writer does not like this characteristic about the show. He or she later says the program has "a wealth of off-putting characters and their stink holes". Here, 'stink holes' can be identified with a wallowing place in which people wallow. "Off-putting" is something (such as wallowing neck-deep in self-pity and debasement) that you do not find attractive.